# Azure find out which permission is needed for certain action

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

I am trying to give permissions to manage locks on resource groups. Atm I gave permission to write locks with following permissions.
"Microsoft.Authorization/*",
"Microsoft.Authorization/locks/*"
But the person is only able to manage locks on resources, not on resource groups.

[image]

Is there an easy way to find out which permission is needed to perform a certain action?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign ***[User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator)*** to that specific User in the Subscription Scope . You can go to `Subscription >> IAM >> Add role Assignment and select User Access Administration and then in members select the user you want to give permissions`.

**OR**

If you want to give only access to locks then you can create a ***[Custom Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal)*** following the below steps :

1. Go to ***Subscription***>> ***IAM***>> ***Add***>> ***Add a Custom
   Role***. [image]
2. Give ***Custom Role Name*** and select ***Start from Scratch***.
   [image]
3. In ***Permissions*** Tab , Click ***Add Permissions*** and search for
   `Microsoft.Autorization` and select it and then again search for
   `Microsoft.Autorization/Locks` and ***select the three permissions*** as
   shown below and ***click on Add***:
   [image]
4. In all other tabs let it be default and in last tab i.e.
   ***review+create*** , click on ***create***. Once its created Go to
   **Subscriptions** >> **IAM** >> **Add** >> **Add role assignment** and ***search the newly created role*** and ***assign it to the user*** you want .

***Note :*** If you are assigning the permissions on ***Resource Group Level*** then you will be only able to manage the locks of the resources present inside the resource group , but if you assign the same permissions on ***Subscription Level*** then you can manage locks on resource groups as well as resources.